# PDO Transactions Locks?

Tags: php, mysql, transactions, pdo, innodb

I have done extensive research about MySQL transactions via the PHP PDO interface.  I am still a little fuzzy about the actual background workings of the transaction methods.  Specifically, I need to know if there is any reason that I should want to prevent all my queries (SELECTs included) inside a transaction spanning from the beginning of the script to the end?  Of course, handling any error in the transaction and rolling them back if need be.

I want to know if there is any locking going on during a transaction and if so, is it row level locking because it is InnoDB?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10914179/1329367

Comment: I'm not an expert so will comment instead of answer but I think it depends on what you do inside the transaction. If you're updating a single row, that row will be locked. if you're dropping a table, the table will be (all assuming the underlying provider supports it) The downside to having a single page-long transaction is obv that anything you lock causes other pages to wait, effectively making your server single-threaded if it's doing lots of work that requires locks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't do that.

The reason for this is that transactions take advantage of [MVCC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiversion_concurrency_control) a mechanism by which every piece of data updated is in fact not update-in-place but merely inserted in somewhere else.

MVCC implies allocating memory and or storage space to accumulate and operate all of the changes you send it without committing them to disk until you issue a `COMMIT`.

That means that while your entire script runs all changes are stored until the script ends. And all of the records that you try and change during the transaction are marked as "work in progress" so that other processes/threads can know that this data will soon be invalidated.

Having certain pieces of data marked as "work in progress" for the entire length of the script means that any **other** concurrent update will see the flag and say "i have to wait until this finishes so I'll get the most recent data".

This includes `SELECTS` depending on isolation levels. Selecting stuff that is marked as "work in progress" may not be what you want because some tables that you may want to join may contain already updated data while other tables are not updated yet resulting in a dirty read.

Transactionality and atomicity of operations is desirable but costly. Use it where it's needed. Yes that means more work for you to figure out where race conditions can happen and even if race conditions occur you have to make the decision if they are really critical or is "some" data loss/mix acceptable.

Would you like your logs and visit counters and other statistics to drag down the speed of your entire site? Or is the quality of **that** information sacrificable for speed (as long as it's not an analytics suit you can afford the occasional collision).

Would you like a seat reservation application to miss-fire and allow more users to grab a seat even after the seat cout was 0? of course not - here you want to leverage transactions and isolation levels to ensure that never happens.

Comment: You are talking about using it for data consistency reasons, I am talking about using it from a pure performance perspective. Data consistency is a very nice bonus of using transactions. Having 50ms spent on each query update/insert outside of a transaction is terribly slow and will hamper down a fast experience on a website.  I guess I have some re-thinking to do about the architecture of the program.

Comment: So you are suggesting having the script run a little longer to ensure that the database operations happen as fast and with little impact with other page loads as possible?  Pretty much, auto committing each update or insert?

Comment: No, i am suggesting you use transactions only with the updates that need them. (Single table updates are atomic by nature, btw). Such as a complex update that reads data from 1-or-more tables and writes data into 1-or-more tables. Using it over most selects would not be usefull. Over inserts not useful.

Comment: So don't begin a transaction at the beginning of the script. And don't end it at the end of the script. Don't use it at all if you don't understand how it works well enough to find out where you need it. Use it over places where you read stuff process the stuff then update the stuff.

Comment: @MihaiStancu Most of what you mentioned is best practices and advisable to follow them. However it should also be noted that transactions can be used to improve performance on inserts and update statements. For an instance if you are performing multiple inserts/updates it's better to run them in a single transaction so that you can avoid writing the data to the disk for each statement as well as adjusting the indexes. Read more here to understand how inserts/updates work http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/commit.html. Also check this http://:goo.gl/NOJni.

Comment: That's true - multiple writes means more disk-i/o while transactoinal writes means bulk dumping the activity log so less disk-i/o. But using transactions over large imports for example means allocating a lot of memory for the MVCC to keep the data and may end up writing to swap and thrashing the memory. Balance is key.

Comment: @MihaiStancu Bulk import requires a different strategy altogether, delayed inserts, use load data etc... I am not whether the question applies to this context.

Comment: The question does not mention at all weather it's a read-intensive / change-intensive / write-intensive application. It asks if it's a **general good practice** to use transactions over the entire span of an application.