# Long running job & sql transaction

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, transactions

Let's say I have a table containing data about robots and one of the columns is the current autonomy of the robot. I have a node job that call a PHP script every minute that is supposed to select all robots that are not fully charged ("*current_autonomy < max_autonomy*"), then update them by a certain amount (coming from the database as well).

To do so, I start a transaction, I select all robots that need to be updated, then I browse them ("*foreach*") and execute an "*UPDATE*" query. I'm not doing just a big "*UPDATE*" because if "*current_autonomy + reload > max_autonomy allowed*", then, the autonomy should be set on "*max_autonomy_allowed*" and not be incremented by "*reload*" (in order to avoid the current autonomy to be higher than the max allowed).

It is working pretty well, but I'm thinking that it could cause some issue when I have a lot of records in the database. Indeed, say that there is a huge amount of data and the script takes 10 seconds to execute. Say also that the robot "X" has been selected because it has an autonomy of "90/100". Then the foreach starts and robots start to be updated.

Now, say that before the script update the robot "X", the player who owns it make an action that is supposed to reduce its autonomy by 2. Will the action query wait until the job's script is done or not (because of table locking ?) ? If it does not, does that mean that the autonomy will be reduced, then updated by the script ? Because if it is the case, when the "*SELECT*" of the job selected the robot data, it selected "90" as the current autonomy, and when it will update this value, it will do "90 + reload" and not "88 + reload", so it will be like the player didn't pay his last action.

I don't know if I'm very clear, please ask me for more details if you don't understand because I'm really interested by this question (figures...).

The thing is that I read a lot of articles/posts (including this one: [PDO Transactions Locks?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12058070/pdo-transactions-locks)) and some people say "use transactions for everything" while others say "use them just when you're sure that you absolutely need them".

For now, all my requests are wrapped into a transaction, even atomic select or insert and I'm considering changing that in order to use transactions only when it is really needed, but I read an article saying "if you don't know if you should use a transaction, then use it", so I'm a bit lost.

A general info: my project is a game composed of pages that make queries to execute some actions. There is also some node js cron jobs that call some php scripts to execute scheduled operation (such as updating robot autonomy or sending mail to players when some condition are met, etc...) and I'd like it to be the most efficient possible. What I really don't want is for the site to become extra slow if there is a lot of user just because transactions are locking tables everywhere.

Thanks for your answers

Comment: It seems very likely you can do the transaction in mysql without pulling the data into php and running loops. There are conditional control structures in mysql such as `IF` and `CASE` that can fix your problem with not exceeding `max_autonomy`. Also, checkout [Consistent Nonlocking Reads](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/innodb-consistent-read.html) from the MySQL manual

Comment: I thought about that but what if the single "update" query takes a long time to execute as well ? The same behaviour could occur no? Even tough, I don't see how I could make it more performant than a single query... And for the other question, what is the best? Using transactions everywhere or only where I need them?

Comment: If you use `InnoDB` and execute a single query using `START TRANSACTION WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT` then your app will continue while the operation executes with consistent data (ie not partially updated data) - there would be no noticeable change for users except that overall db server load may be higher. Once the operation completes the new data would be accessible to users.

Comment: For now, I'm using transactions for every query via the PDO "beginTransaction" method. I guess I'll have to replace that with the query "START TRANSACTION WITH CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT" ? And... Sorry to ask again but, what is the best approach ? Transactions for everything or just where it is needed ?

Comment: The main reason to use `beginTransaction` is to allow for rollbacks, so if you're not checking for errors that require a rollback then it's unnecessary. I can't answer based on the information you have provided. You need to consider the implications of your app data structure and usage patterns to determine when you need to use `CONSISTENT SNAPSHOT` if there is the potential to serve out of sync data due to long queries resulting in partially updated data at a point in time. I'd suggest researching `InnoDB` start transaction, row locking, and snapshots to determine your best solution.

Comment: Ok, will do, thanks for the advices.

Answer (score 1):

To lessen the burden you can use the InnoDB storage engine for MySQL or any other DB table provider that implements row-locking instead of table locking.

Other than that, you have 2 choices.
Refactor your infrastructure or add more resources to your server to deal with slowness. There is only so much optimizing you can do.

Comment: I am already using InnoDB. For the refactoring, I don't really how I could do that. At the end, I still will need some job to execute some queries. Of course, I'm not in production yet and maybe I won't have any performance issue. I just want to make this sure upfront :-D

Comment: I don't see anything bad with your approach. But like everything in this universe resources are limited, and you will have to increase those resources when you get enough users. At which point going from a single server application to a multi-server is going to be a pain. My suggestion would be to keep that in mind when you are designing your application as it will limit the headaches later